# Composition on WriterT monad value?

Tags: haskell

Let's have a function returning a monad writer of the following type:

`getWriter :: a -> WriterT w IO a`

Now I'm having some troubles at writing composition function of the following signature:

`composeWAct :: (IO a -> IO a) -> (a -> WriterT w IO a) -> a -> WriterT w IO a`

The first argument `IO a -> IO a` is intended to be applied on WriterT's monadic value.
Example use: `composeWAct (print "Hello !" >>) getWriter`

I'm looking for a composition solution - ie. *without* need to run/eval the writer.

So far I've attempted to implement `composeWAct` like function with use of standard modules Control.Monad and Control.Monad.Writer:

`composeWAct' iofn = ((ap . liftIO) (iofn return id) .)`

but it obviously does not meet the requirements.

Can anybody help with the implementation or at least show the right path ?

Thanks.

Comment: "*without* the need to run/eval the writer" -- I don't think you're going to achieve this.  At some point you will need to unwrap the Writer to get at the IO action inside.  There is no general solution here, it depends on the transformer.

Comment: @luqui Thanks. I was worried about no general solution would be possible. However would appreciate even attempts with implementation which would unwrap the Writer monad.

Comment: @luqui Here is an example where did I get without unwrapping: `let wtcomp= (ap . liftIO) (print "Hello" >> return id) . const wt` where `wt :: WriterT String IO String`. Then run the composed monad: `runWriterT $ wtcomp ()` produces expected `"Hello"` and `("value", "logging info")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a library function with a slightly different type that may serve your needs: [`hoist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) from the [`mmorph`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph) package. Its type can be specialized to `(forall a. IO a -> IO a) -> WriterT w IO b -> WriterT w IO b`. It composes a little differently than the function you imagine. (I'm not sure what you mean by not needing to run/eval the writer. Look at the implementation of `hoist` for `WriterT` if you're concerned about its internal workings.)

Here's a worked-out example.

```
prefixHello :: IO a -> IO a
prefixHello m = print "Hello" >> m

myWriter :: a -> WriterT String IO a
myWriter x = tell "logging info" >> return x

wtcomp :: WriterT String IO String
wtcomp = hoist prefixHello $ myWriter "value"

ghci> runWriterT $ wtcomp
"Hello"
("value","logging info")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll attempt to wrap my head around and report back if it does suit the need.

Comment: By the way, don't be worried about seeing runWriterT various places. If you look at the Monad instance for WriterT, you'll find that every monadic bind--every new line in a do-expression, or every use of the function 'ap'--involves runWriterT.

Comment: Oh, thanks ! I can see now avoiding runWriter was unjustified and that makes things much easier now.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @ChristianConkle's approach, you can use [`MonadBaseControl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#g:3), which is designed do give you access to the underlying base monad of a monad stack. In most cases, the base monad is `IO`, and `MonadBaseControl` allows you to lift many different `IO` functions (such as `fork`) into an `IO`-based monad stack (see the [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base) package).

There are several utility functions in `Control.Monad.Trans.Control` that can be directly used for your task. In particular, the following two can be specialized as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control

liftBaseOp' :: (MonadBaseControl b m)
            => (forall c . (a -> b c) -> b c) -> (a -> m d) -> m d
liftBaseOp' f = liftBaseOp f

liftBaseOp_' :: (MonadBaseControl b m)
             => (forall a . b a -> b a) -> m c -> m c
liftBaseOp_' f = liftBaseOp_ f
```

So you can write

```
wtcomp :: WriterT String IO String
wtcomp = liftBaseOp_ prefixHello $ myWriter "value"
```

The advantage is that `liftBaseOp_` gives you access to `IO` no matter how deep the monad stack is.

Comment: Thanks ! I've missed to look into `Control.Monad.Trans.Control`. The good thing it's a part of haskell-platform so no extra module need to be installed.